# 'random_sample' is not defined when using pip

Tags: python, pip

I was trying to use celery, but ran into some compilation errors. As such, I tried to uninstall/reinstall Numpy and Skimage in an attempt to fix it.

I did *not* fix it, instead, I made it worse.

When I now use pip to install, uninstall or --upgrade it returns the following error.

```
rootadmin@annotatie01:/data_nfs/opensurfaces/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy$ sudo -H python -m pip install pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 151, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, loader, code, fname = _get_module_details(mod_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
    loader = get_loader(mod_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 464, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 474, in find_loader
    for importer in iter_importers(fullname):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 430, in iter_importers
    __import__(pkg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from .packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 17, in <module>
    from httplib import HTTPConnection, HTTPException
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 80, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "random/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    ranf = random = sample = random_sample
NameError: name 'random_sample' is not defined
```

The same error is returned if i run `python -m pip.__main__`. I'm using a remote server running ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your current working directory is

```
/data_nfs/opensurfaces/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
```

which is *inside* the `numpy` package, so `import random` results in importing not the standard library `random` module, but the `numpy.random` package.  Just cd out of that directory (in general don't run Python from inside packages under `site-packages`).

Even if you didn't know there were a `numpy.random` module you can glean this from the traceback:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 35, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "random/__init__.py", line 102, in <module>
    ranf = random = sample = random_sample
```

You can see that while `tempfile` was imported from an absolute path `/usr/lib/python2.7/` (where the standard library is), `random` was imported from a relative path, that is, relative to your current directory.

Comment: Ah, that was deceptively simple. Thank you.

Comment: If that fixes it please kindly accept the answer :)

Comment: There's a minimal timer. But will do.